# Why did AudioQueueAllocateBuffer fail?

Tags: ios, audio, audiotoolbox, audioqueue

Device: iPhone X

System: OS 15.1

I came across an error when using AudioQueue to play some data. The error is returned by this API and its value is `-308`.

```
OSStatus status = AudioQueueAllocateBuffer(_audioQueue, MIN_SIZE_PER_FRAME, &audioQueueBuffers[i]);
```

After that, All the AudioQueue APIs will return the error `-66671`. The official documents define as below.

```
kAudioQueueErr_QueueInvalidated
In iOS, the audio server has exited, causing the audio queue to become invalid.
```

However, I have no idea what the audio server means. Could any guy tell me what had happened?

Comment: Show your code for playing audio

Answer (score 0):

This problem may be caused by an abnormal shutdown of the media service。The solution is to destroy the audioQueue and recreate it when you got an error。
See [https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/693371。](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/693371%E3%80%82)
Refer to the Apple Media Engineer's answers。